# Migrating Google Authenticator secret keys between servers

Tags: pam, google-authenticator, totp

I got an OpenVPN server (ubuntu 14.04) with `pam-google-authenticator (20130529-2)` 
I'm trying to create a new OpenVPN server (ubuntu 18.04) with `pam-google-authenticator (20170702-1)` 
and migrate all the existing secret keys.

when creating a new key using `google-authenticator` I manage to connect and everything works fine, but when I tried the old keys (copied from the old server), the authentication fail: 
`pamtester openvpn shalevbs authenticate` -> `pamtester: Authentication failure` 
both of the server synched to the same NTP

I also noticed the old secret key is **16 character** while the the new one is **26 characters**.

have anyone encountered something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with your new server running Bit Size of 160 bits, and the older server running 80 bits (the default - maybe old default?)

I believe the size of the secret is defined in libpam/google-authenticator.c on / around line 39.

```
#define SECRET_BITS               80          // Must be divisible by eight
```

Go ahead and check this value on the old and new server and see if changing the new server to the same value as the old server fixes things for you.

Comment: it got fixed by itself, I never did anything special - I guess voodoo